# Shapefile to GeoJson with Rails

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, ogr2ogr, ruby

I have a requirement to create a layer on map, Client have provided me only the shape files(.shp). As i am very new to GIS, i was reading about it and found we need to convert the shapefile into GeoJson and load the co-ordinates on map.

Continued further to convert the .shp file to .geojson.

I used ogr2ogr to convert it from terminal, here is the command which i used

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:4283 data.json data.shp
```

Was giving me an error

```
Unable to open datasource `/home/Gourav/Shape File/2_files/proj1.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> PDF
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> SVG
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
```

I even tried with online tool got the same error in json format.

Does it need any other files like .dbf or .shx or is there any other way to load shapefiles on map, i am coming from rubyonrails (Ruby version is 2.0.0) so could not even make use of **rgeo-shapefile gem**

Please some one tell the meaning of following syntax

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs WGS84 data.geojson data.shp
```

-f gives the datasource of destination?

Asking first time please excuse me if i could not frame my question properly

Comment: Yes, you have to keep all essential parts of shapefile together (`.shp`,`.dbf` and `.shx`). According to documentation http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html `-f` is "*output file format name*".

Comment: Thank you and am i correct for converting shape file to geojson.

Comment: Yes, the command you provided should work. However, if your problem is in missing the rest shapefile files, you should see this error: `ERROR 4: Unable to open data.shx or data.SHX. Try --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true to restore or create it
`. This suggest that you can restore the `.shx` index file, but anyway you lost attribute table stored in `.dbf`.

Comment: @OtoKaláb Thank you i will ask my client to provide with those files.